# Is there a way to make Chris Coyier's responsive "list" table with dynamic content?

Tags: html, css, html-table

Chris Coyier wrote an [excellent article](https://css-tricks.com/responsive-data-tables/) on making HTML tables better on mobile by structuring them as a list. I love the method, but the tables I deal with are dynamic, and I can't really go into the CSS like he does and label each header title using a content tag.

```
/*
Label the data
*/
td:nth-of-type(1):before { content: "First Name"; }
td:nth-of-type(2):before { content: "Last Name"; }
td:nth-of-type(3):before { content: "Job Title"; }
td:nth-of-type(4):before { content: "Favorite Color"; }
td:nth-of-type(5):before { content: "Wars of Trek?"; }
td:nth-of-type(6):before { content: "Porn Name"; }
td:nth-of-type(7):before { content: "Date of Birth"; }
td:nth-of-type(8):before { content: "Dream Vacation City"; }
td:nth-of-type(9):before { content: "GPA"; }
td:nth-of-type(10):before { content: "Arbitrary Data"; }
```

Here's an example of it in action: https://css-tricks.com/examples/ResponsiveTables/responsive.php

But is there a way to make it so I don't have to manually label the headers?

Answer (score 1):

### Dynamic `content` headers with jQuery

We can assign a column number to each cell with `.index()`. The first column cells have an index number of `0`, the second column index is `1`, the third column index is `2`, etc.

Now that we can identify each column with a number, we can give each cell the correct header text.

- Each table header is given a dynamic class based on its column index number starting at `header-0`.

  ```
  $('th').each(function () {
      $(this).addClass('header-' + $(this).index());
  });
  ```
- Each table cell is given a `data-header` attribute containing the text of its corresponding header. It selects the table header by the class and matching index number.

  ```
  $('td').each(function () {
      $(this).attr('data-header', $('.header-' + $(this).index()).text());
  });
  ```

**Note:** There will be a more efficient method to achieve this.

#### Complete Example

Change the text in each `<th>` to see it change for every row.

```js
//Assign class to each header
$('th').each(function() {
  $(this).addClass('header-' + $(this).index());
});

//Assign a data-header attribute with the text from the corresponding header
$('td').each(function() {
  $(this).attr('data-header', $('.header-' + $(this).index()).text());
});
```

```css
/* Force table to not be like tables anymore */

table,
thead,
tbody,
th,
td,
tr {
  display: block;
}
/* Hide table headers (but not display: none;, for accessibility) */

thead tr {
  position: absolute;
  top: -9999px;
  left: -9999px;
}
tr {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
td {
  /* Behave  like a "row" */
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 50%;
}
td:before {
  /* Now like a table header */
  position: absolute;
  /* Top/left values mimic padding */
  top: 6px;
  left: 6px;
  width: 45%;
  padding-right: 10px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  content: attr(data-header);
}
table {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>John</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>John</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>John</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>John</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>John</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

After I saw the article (and the comments) I will copy and paste one of the comments:

Use data attributes for cells so content is in html and not in css:

```
<td data-label="First Name">Doug</td>
```

then css is more like:

```
td:before { content: attr(data-label); }
```